# Why is for looping not looping?

Tags: python, loops

Im new to programming and cannot figure out why this wont loop. It prints and converts the first item exactly how I want. But stops after the first iteration.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

url = 'http://books.toscrape.com/'
page = requests.get(url)

html = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
section = html.find_all('ol', class_='row')

for books in section:
    #Title Element
    header_element = books.find("article", class_='product_pod')
    title_element = header_element.img
    title = title_element['alt']

    #Price Element
    price_element = books.find(class_='price_color')
    price_str = str(price_element.text)
    price = price_str[1:]

    #Create JSON
    final_results_json = {"Title":title, "Price":price}
    final_result = json.dumps(final_results_json, sort_keys=True, indent=1)

    print(title)
    print(price)
    print()
    print(final_result)
```

Comment: Q: Did you happen to check len(section)?  Maybe there's only one book?

Comment: I did there should be 19 or 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is only 1 `<ol>` in that doc

I think you want

`for book in section[0].find_all('li'):`

`ol` means ordered list, of which there is one in this case, there are many `li` or list items in that `ol`

Comment: Oh ok thank you. Was that just a bad element for me to choose? or was I just not specific enough in the for loop?

Comment: you selecteded the list (`ol` ordered list) containing all the movies ... then you just found the first category/title etc in that list ... this selects each entry (`li` (list-item)) in that list and then you are selecting each entries title/category/etc

Comment: OK I think I get it now thanks that was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

First, clarify what you are looking for? Probably, you wish to print the title, price and final_result for every book that has been scraped from the URL books.toscrape.com. The code is working as it is written though the expectation is different. If you notice you are finding all the "ol" tags with class name = "row" and there's just one such element on the page thus, section has only one element eventually the for loop iterates just once.

How to debug it?

1. Check the type of section, type(section)
2. Print the section to know what it contains
3. write some print statements in for loop to understand what happens when

It isn't hard to debug this one.
You need to change:

```
section = html.find_all('li', class_='col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3')
```